# updating instance attributes from global function with many arguments

Tags: python

I have a global function meant to map a class attribute to a class property

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

The class is

```
class toy:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return f(self.x)
```

so

```
t = toy(2)
```

gives 
t.x = 2 and t.y = 4.

If I set t.x=3, I get t.y = 9. This is the desired behavior. My question is this:

What is the proper way to do this with a function of multiple arguments?

For example, if

```
def g(x,a,b):
    return a*x**2+b
```

controlled the property y, and a,b were fixed outside of the class definition, is it okay to write

```
class toy:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return g(self.x,a,b)
```

Or is there a better way to do this? How can I pass global variables into the local scope of a class instance, in order to determine a property of the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial` to create a new function object with certain parameters already passed to it:

```
import functools
def g(a, b, x):
  return a*x**2+b 

g1 = functools.partial(g, 32, 232) #placeholder values
class toy:
  def __init__(self,x):
    self.x=x

  @property
  def y(self):
    return g1(self.x) 

t = toy(100)
>>>t.y
>>>320232
```

It is perfectly fine, however, to declare `a` and `b` outside the class and pass them to `g` in the `property` attribute:

```
a = 100
b = 200
def g(x,a,b):
  return a*x**2+b 

class toy:
  def __init__(self,x):
    self.x=x

 @property
 def y(self):
   return g(self.x, a, b)
```

Lastly, if you have variables that may or may not be used inside the class, consider implementing them as class attributes:

```
class toy:
  a = 100
  b = 200
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
  @property
  def y(self):
    return g(self.x, toy.a, toy.b)
```

Comment: @kevinkayaks Glad to help!

Comment: one more thing-- What if my class is defined in a module which I'm importing. What is best practice for linking the function back into the imported module?

Comment: @kevinkayaks I would reverse the imports i.e store the function in the module, import the function, and use the class from `__main__`. However, if you do want to import the class, also store the function in another module. That way you can import the class, which imports the function. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This makes sense. I can just make a function module and import that into the class module